# php soap call problem passing a parameter

Tags: php, soap

I've created this SOAP call

```
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enable', 0 );
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0 );
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1500); 

$loc        = "https://MyEndPoint";
$urlWSDL    = $loc . ".wsdl";

$ops = array(
    'trace'         => 1,
    'exceptions'    => 0,       
    'compression'   => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
    'style'         => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'use'           => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_1,
    "ResponseType"  => "Xml",
    'encoding'      => 'UTF-8'
);

try 
{
    $clientSOAP = new SoapClient($urlWSDL, $ops);
    $clientSOAP->__setLocation($loc);   
} 
catch (e $exception) {
        ECHO "WS not active";
}

try {
    $params = array(
            "customer id='reset'"    => "Cust " ,    
            "value"  => "MyValue"                         
    );

    $result = $clientSOAP->sendCustomer($params);

    $strresult =  $clientSOAP->__getLastResponse();

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo '<h2>EXCEPTION</h2>';  
    echo "det.::\n" . $clientSOAP->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
    echo $exception;      
}
```

But I alway get an error in line

```
"customer id='reset'"    => "Cust " ,
```

removing

> id='reset'

the call works correctly, but I need to pass that id.

Any ideas?

I've tried with no results:

```
 "customer id=&quot;reset&quot;"    => "Cust " ,
```

I've also tried to replace double quotes by single, but I get an error always in the same line

I have also tried to make the call from third party software, and the call is made correctly and the results are as expected

Comment: Can you post the documentation on how the `$params` should be constructed. The key looks "weird". I may be able to help you based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

The structure should be

```
<customer id='reset'>
myCust  
</customer>
```

Thanks
Jam